# Linux ssh connection without pts

Tags: ssh, tty, sshd, pts

I'm connecting to my server using JSCH and I can't find the login user with the following commands :

```
who
w
```

I found that it's not connected as pts :

```
# netstat -tuplena | grep :22
  ......    14918/sshd: root
```

the `who` command shows only pts :
2764/sshd: root@pts

can anyone explain how it connected without pts and why `who` can't show it ?

---

I believe this should be interactive non-login shell , is there any command to run interactive non-login shell from different host ?

Answer (score 0):

JSCH is a java implementation of SSH2. You connect directly to a remote server's existing process.
 Not a process like you get on login.

If you want to "do things" (port forwarding, X11 forwarding, file transfer)
 you integrate its as part your own Java programs. It does not create a new user process on the remote site like you seem to want.

Comment: it's still not clear how to connect directly using existing process. how can I login without "user process" ? is there steps from terminal ?

Comment: What you need: emulate in java what the system does for a console login https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475480/is-it-possible-to-get-a-login-prompt-on-a-remote-server-directly-after-boot

Comment: This might be more helpful - create a java console object and then login if you want a plain login: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-console-class

Comment: you have almost give me the answer , I think this is interactive non login shell right ? what is the command used to enter interactive non login shell ?